Django Application hosting on different servers but uses the same database
I have a django project called django_project and a domain website.com , I want to host the subdomains of this on different server.
So ,
django project  Server A website.com
django project  Server b sub.website.com
django project  Server b sub2.website.com
Somethins like this.
How do I do this ?My server RHEL9
